# PHP : Don't understand extension system

Tags: php

I recently needed to do multithreading with PHP so I compiled version 7.4 from source to have ZTS mode enabled (required to use Parallel new extension) :

- I cloned the PHP source repo on my server
- `git checkout PHP-7.4`
- `./buildconf --force`
- I took this configuration string from a tutorial, I have to admit that I didn't really understand all the options :

  CONFIGURE_STRING="--prefix=/etc/phpzts --with-bz2 --with-zlib --enable-zip --disable-cgi 
  --enable-soap --enable-intl --with-openssl --with-readline --with-curl --enable-ftp 
  --enable-mysqlnd --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --enable-sockets 
  --enable-pcntl --with-pspell --with-enchant --with-gettext --with-gd --enable-exif 
  --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir --with-freetype-dir --with-xsl --enable-bcmath 
  --enable-mbstring --enable-calendar --enable-simplexml --enable-json --enable-hash 
  --enable-session --enable-xml --enable-wddx --enable-opcache --with-pcre-regex 
  --with-config-file-path=/etc/phpzts/config --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/phpzts/config 
  --enable-cli --enable-debug --enable-fpm --with-fpm-user=www-data --with-fpm-group=www-data 
  --with-mcrypt --enable-sysvmsg --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-shmop --enable-parallel 
  --enable-maintainer-zts"
- `./configure $CONFIGURE_STRING`
- `make && make install`
- copied php.ini file from the php-src repo to phpzts/config (confimed it was loaded successfully by doing a `/etc/phpzts/bin/php --ini`)

All the functions that are supposed to be loaded from php extensions work well in my scripts, especially mb_string functions, openssl functions, parallel functions. **That's what I don't understand**. I was expecting to install them through `apt-get install php7.4-mbstring` for exemple, just like what I do with the other php installed for apache. All the extensions are commented in the php.ini file template that I just copied from the source repo :

```
;extension=imap
;extension=ldap
;extension=mbstring
;extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
;extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
;extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
...
```

Despite everything is commented, it looks like all these librairies are loaded by php because I found their lines when typing `/etc/phpzts/bin/php -m`, and I can use them. How can they be loaded while they are commented in php.ini file ?

Moreover, when I uncomment `extension=openssl` for exemple, php says "unable to load dynamic librairy". The extension_dir folder contains nothing except a file called opcache.so and another opcache.a.

How php can actually load all these extensions while there is nothing in the extension folder ? Why openssl is loaded (I can use the functions in it), but php still says "Cannot load dynamic librairy" when I uncomment `extension=openssl` line in php.ini ? Why do I have to run `apt-get install php7.4-mbstring` when I want to install a php extension for apache version of php, while it looks like all extensions are pre-installed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have compiled the modules static to the php binary. Look here http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/php5/build_system/building_extensions.html

> As you already know from the previous section, PHP extensions can be either built statically into the PHP binary, or compiled into a shared object (.so). Static linkage is the default for most of the bundled extensions, whereas shared objects can be created by explicitly passing --enable-EXTNAME=shared or --with-EXTNAME=shared to ./configure.

Comment: Thank you, this link is helpfull for understanding, I didn't know there were 2 ways to load extensions. I guess when you do apt-get install php7.4-mbstring, it brings a .so librairy into the "default" (where?) extension directory and enable it in php.ini file right ?

Comment: Yes the location depends on your linux distribution on debian it is somewhere on /usr/lib/php